# C++ Class to Void Pointer, Data Lost?

Tags: c++, serialization, network-programming, void-pointers

(This was mistakenly post in GameDev. Thanks to the moderators there for the point in the correct location to ask!)

I am casting a simple struct to a void pointer so it can be sent out on the network, but it is cutting off my second variable for reasons unknown to me.

I have found a few similar threads, notably [this one](https://rubentorresbonet.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/an-overview-of-data-serialization-techniques-in-c/), which has been a great help. I am reasonably certain this is a "newbie mistake" or I am overlooking something exceedingly simple.

Any input is appreciated, so thank you in advance!

```
/* struct provided */
struct Login_Struct
{
/*000*/ char username[32];
/*032*/ char password[64];
/*096*/
};


void NetWrapper::sendLogin(std::string user, std::string pass)
{
    // ensure size constraints are met
    if( user.length() > sizeof(Login_Struct::username)
    ||  pass.length() > sizeof(Login_Struct::password)) { return; }

    std::string hashPass = Security::strSHA256(pass); // returns hashed password

    Login_Struct login; // empty struct
    //strncpy(login.username, user.c_str(), user.length()); // i.e 'bob'
    //strncpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), hashPass.length()); // hashed password (64 char)
    memcpy(login.username, user.c_str(), user.length()); 
    memcpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), hashPass.length());

    char* pData = new char[sizeof(Login_Struct)];
    //memcpy(static_cast<void*>(pData), static_cast<void*>(&login), sizeof(Login_Struct)); // serialize data for sending
    memcpy(pData, &login, sizeof(Login_Struct)); // serialize data for sending

    // if we have data, send it and cleanup
    if(pData) { m_network->send(pData, OP_Login); delete pData; } // Network::send(char* d, short opCode)
    pData = nullptr;
}
```

Additionally, debug output looks like this (omitted from code for readability, can supply if needed/requested):

```
NetWrapper::sendLogin: Login_Struct Dump [bob] (bob), [5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8] (password)
DEBUG: username maxlength [32], user length [3]
DEBUG: password maxlength [64], pass length [64]
DEBUG: pData [x=�i=], [0x7ffc5e4fd0e0], sizeof(Login_Struct) [96], sizeof(login) [96]
NetWrapper::sendLogin: New pData! pData [x=�i=]
NetWrapper::sendLogin: Post memcpy! pData [bob]
Network::send : Sending [d0c8504000100bob] ## ignore characters preceding "bob"
```

@wondra mentioned on my incorrectly located post that it is an issue of the null terminator killing it for me. I have made adjustments to copy the string without the null terminator, but I am either misunderstanding how it is placed or that is not the issue.

---

EDIT: Adding code with debug nonsense to help this make sense. Thanks to all that have replied so far! (And yes, I am embarrassed at having resorted to cout spam. Open to suggestions on better/cleaner methods!)

```
void NetWrapper::sendLogin(std::string user, std::string pass)
{
    if( user.length() > sizeof(Login_Struct::username)
    ||  pass.length() > sizeof(Login_Struct::password)) { return; }

    std::string hashPass = Security::strSHA256(pass);

    Login_Struct login;
    memset(&login, 0, sizeof(Login_Struct)); // clear buffer
    strncpy(login.username, user.c_str(), user.length());
    strncpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), hashPass.length());
    //memcpy(login.username, user.c_str(), user.length());
    //memcpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), hashPass.length());

    std::cout<<"NetWrapper::sendLogin: Login_Struct Dump ["<<login.username<<"] ("<<user<<"), ["<<login.password<<"] ("<<pass<<")\n";
    std::cout<<"DEBUG: username maxlength ["<<sizeof(login.username)<<"], user length ["<<user.length()<<"], user size ["<<sizeof(user)<<"]\n";
    std::cout<<"DEBUG: password maxlength ["<<sizeof(login.password)<<"], pass length ["<<hashPass.length()<<"], pass size ["<<sizeof(hashPass)<<"]\n";

    char* pData = new char[sizeof(Login_Struct)];
    std::cout<<"DEBUG: pData ["<<pData<<"], sizeof(pData) ["<<sizeof(pData)<<"], sizeof(&pData) ["<<sizeof(&pData)<<"], ["<<static_cast<void*>(&login)<<"], sizeof(Login_Struct) ["<<sizeof(Login_Struct)<<"], sizeof(login) ["<<sizeof(login)<<"]\n";
    std::cout<<"NetWrapper::sendLogin: New pData! pData ["<<pData<<"], sizeof(pData) ["<<sizeof(pData)<<"], sizeof(&pData) ["<<sizeof(&pData)<<"]\n";
    /// ------------------
    //memcpy(static_cast<void*>(pData), static_cast<void*>(&login), sizeof(Login_Struct)); // serialize data for sending
    memcpy(pData, &login, sizeof(Login_Struct)); // serialize data for sending
    /// ------------------
    std::cout<<"NetWrapper::sendLogin: Post memcpy! pData ["<<pData<<"], sizeof(pData) ["<<sizeof(pData)<<"], sizeof(&pData) ["<<sizeof(&pData)<<"], sizeof(*pData) ["<<sizeof(*pData)<<"]\n";

    // if we have data, send it and cleanup
    if(pData) { m_network->send(pData, OP_Login); delete pData; }
    pData = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "it is cutting off my second variable" means. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: How does `m_network->send` know how much data to send?

Comment: SHA256 is not sutable for hashing passwords, so the security of this system is immediately suspect. The fixed length fields are also ripe for buffer overflow attacks, there's no bounds checking being done here. This is why you use `std::string` whenever possible.

Comment: If you want to send this over the network, don't use fixed-sized buffers. Use something like Pascal strings: One byte for length, plus variable length content. Normally 255 characters is enough for things like this. If you need more you can go UTF-8 style, the first byte, if > 127, is paired with the second for length and so on.

Comment: Another thing to note is you should be sending raw passwords over TLS, that sending a pre-hashed password means your login security is extremely flimsy. Even when SHA256 was used for passwords, which was some time ago, they were salted, and if properly salted you can't compare a hashed guess vs. a saved known-good hash. It's basically impossible. SMTP used to use a form of this, [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), but it's basically useless as TLS is way, *way* stronger.

Comment: @tadman, while off-topic and unrelated to my original question, that is a wonderful amount of information. 

tl;dr - Thank You!

Longer: I am using this as a test bed to get network pieces working. I didn't see a point to building a coded "fort knox" when I couldn't relay data between the client & server correctly. Will definitely keep your comments in my personal notes for the network and security classes (when I get to that step)!

Comment: Good luck with your project! I'm just concerned that decisions made now might be cemented in there and very difficult to undo and fix later. Safety is no joke these days. People will crack anything and everything.

Comment: @tadman I am a Linux Sysadmin by trade. I completely understand your concerns and share them as well. Given this is both a "for-fun" project and a "re-learning C++" project...mistakes will be made...in gigantic quantities. :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning. One thing to look at for inspiration is using JSON for transport, or [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) if you're of a more raw-binary mindset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it's not clear what exactly your problem is. There are a couple potential problems I see though.

You're method of viewing if your code is working will not work.

```
std::cout<<"NetWrapper::sendSerialized: Post memcpy! pData ["<<pData<<"], sizeof(pData) ["<<sizeof(pData)<<"], sizeof(&pData) ["<<sizeof(&pData)<<"], sizeof(*pData) ["<<sizeof(*pData)<<"]\n";
```

The char array `pData` will contain two char buffers holding two strings. If your test name is 'bob' then there will be a null char after and that's all that it will show using `cout`.
You'll need a function to dump the contents of your buffer, or else possibly do something like `printf("password='%.*s'", 64, pData + 32)`. That's for you to figure out.

Another problem is you're using `memcpy()` but not clearing the memory of the buffer before. It's undefined what's in the buffer past the string you're copying over.

You're sending this out over the network so your strings can end up not being null terminated. That might be okay, or it might not. It depends on what's expected.
It would definitely cause an issue if something on the receiving end is expecting a valid null terminated C string. Or also trying to use something like `printf()` on them.

This will fix the problem of not clearing the memory first, assuming it's sending **not** as a null terminated string:

```
memset(&login, 0, sizeof(login));
strncpy(login.username, user.c_str(), sizeof(login.username)); 
strncpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), sizeof(login.password));
```

The first `memset()` clears all the bytes to be 0, and `strncpy()` makes sure not to copy more chars than is available in destination buffer.

If the problem is that it **does** expect a null terminated C string, then you'll need to add `+1` to the size of the char arrays to hold the null terminator, and then copy them as:

```
memset(&login, 0, sizeof(login));
strncpy(login.username, user.c_str(), sizeof(login.username)-1); 
strncpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), sizeof(login.password)-1);
```

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't `NULL` terminate if the content is too long to fit, so you may need to force-`NULL` this string manually or limit to `sizeof(x)-1`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that originally too. This will be sent out over the network so it's not necessary for it to be a null terminated string. As I pointed out though this can be a problem if trying to print it out as null terminated when it's not.

Comment: For it to be null terminated it would have to add one more char to the buffer size which I'm assuming the other side is not expecting that size. It looks like the password hash is full at 64.

Comment: "Not necessary" is a pretty wild assumption to make here. There's a very high probability that on the receiving side these will be used as-is. This structure is really inadequate for the task at hand.

Comment: Yeah, actually it's not clear either way based on how this question was asked.
True, `sizeof(x)-1` would be needed if maintaining null terminated strings, which is what I put originally.

Comment: @MrJLP,

Thank you for your reply! The issue is that when I use memcpy or strncopy to fill the fields, they appear normally. However, when I use the memcpy to pData ( `memcpy(pData, &login, sizeof(Login_Struct));` ) It only keeps the username variable. I attempted the use of strncpy with the string length to omit the null terminator, to hopefully bypass this. If this is not clear, please let me know and I will attempt to reword.

Thank you again!

Comment: @BeauB.It would be helpful to describe exactly and concisely what the problem is and how you know that. I'm still not exactly sure what "It only keeps the username variable" means either. Do you mean the `password` field is full of null chars? Is it truncated? How are you determining this? Since these are not null terminated C strings you'll need to be careful about how it's printed out

Comment: @MrJLP, that is fair and thank you again for your continued assistance. I am looking to pass a username and password, in string form, to this function. From here, ensure they meet the length requirements/max of the **Login_Struct**, serialize, and send to the **Network** class for transmission. My _cout_ spam is more for me to visually track things, as I learn better visually when stuck. From the line " _NetWrapper::sendSerialized: Post memcpy!..._ ", it only shows the pData as being [bob] (mentioned in original debug block). The Network::send function also shows a string with a length of 3.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at `NetWrapper::sendSerialized` to get down to the bottom of what's going on. From what's presented here it's hard to tell what's going on. For all we know there could be a bug in that part of the code, or elsewhere in between

Comment: Actually, here's what you can do. Verify that the `Login` struct is valid after copying to `pData`.

Comment: Hold on. Your `cout` is working as expected and not showing the password, even though it could be there. There is a `\0` terminating char after "bob" which ends the string, so the password won't be shown.

Comment: You'll need a valid way to show what's in your struct. Good luck. Mark as resolved if this fixes your prob. I'll update answer. Resolve if it works out

Comment: @MrJLP, you nailed it. When I added a debug block to deserialize it **before** the handoff to m_network->send(), it came back with my password. Got stuck spinning my wheels, so to speak, because of a null terminator wrecking my cout. Marking it as the answer and updating my original post. **THANK YOU!**

Answer (score 0):

[Solution by the original asker:](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44166789/4)

> ANSWER: This was an issue of me not clearing the buffer and then me
>   getting caught by cout and a null terminator. The bit below is working
>   (and debug output below). Huge thanks to MrJLP for the time/effort!
>
> ```
> void NetWrapper::sendLogin(std::string user, std::string pass)
> {
>     if( user.length() > sizeof(Login_Struct::username)
>     ||  pass.length() > sizeof(Login_Struct::password)) { return; }
>
>     std::string hashPass = Security::strSHA256(pass);
>
>     Login_Struct login;
>     memset(&login, 0, sizeof(Login_Struct)); // clear buffer
>     strncpy(login.username, user.c_str(), user.length());
>     strncpy(login.password, hashPass.c_str(), hashPass.length());
>
>     std::cout<<"NetWrapper::sendLogin: Login_Struct Dump ["<<login.username<<"] ("<<user<<"), ["<<login.password<<"] ("<<pass<<")\n";
>     std::cout<<"DEBUG: username maxlength ["<<sizeof(login.username)<<"], user length ["<<user.length()<<"], user size ["<<sizeof(user)<<"]\n";
>     std::cout<<"DEBUG: password maxlength ["<<sizeof(login.password)<<"], pass length ["<<hashPass.length()<<"], pass size ["<<sizeof(hashPass)<<"]\n";
>
>     char* pData = new char[sizeof(Login_Struct)];
>     memcpy(pData, &login, sizeof(Login_Struct)); // serialize data for sending
>
>     Login_Struct dslogin;
>     memset(&dslogin, 0, sizeof(Login_Struct)); // clear buffer
>     memcpy(&dslogin, pData, sizeof(Login_Struct));
>     std::cout<<"NetWrapper::sendLogin: Test Dump ["<<dslogin.username<<"] ["<<dslogin.password<<"]\n";
>
>     // if we have data, send it and cleanup
>     if(pData) { m_network->send(pData, OP_Login); delete pData; }
>     pData = nullptr;
> }
> ```
>
> And debug output:
>
> ```
> NetWrapper::sendLogin: Login_Struct Dump [bob] (bob), [5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8��lY�] (password)
> DEBUG: username maxlength [32], user length [3], user size [32]
> DEBUG: password maxlength [64], pass length [64], pass size [32]
> NetWrapper::sendLogin: Test Dump [bob] [5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8]
> ```